# How do I URLEncode a string while keeping certain characters?

Tags: java, urlencode

I have the following bit of code converting a path into a uri:

```
uri.append(String.format("%s/", URLEncoder.encode(groupName, UTF_8.name())));
```

...where groupName can contain `/` characters. By default, URLEncoder converts these to `%2F`and this doesn't work for me. My first thought is to take this approach:

```
URLEncoder.encode(groupName, UTF_8.name()).replaceAll("%2F", "/")
```

But that feels kind of hacky. Is there a more conventional way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to exclude slash?

Comment: The service I am accessing indicates subgroups through directory structures similar to java namespaces, with a slash.

Comment: Does decoding it on the server-side not work, if already tried.

Comment: That service is maintained by a different team. I _could_ get them to change it, but that would take forever and be more trouble than just adhering to their contract.